# Nginx ожидание слушателя

Tags: nginx

Есть такой конфиг nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Всё работает прекрасно. На 8000 порту работает бэкенд. Но представим ситуацию, что этот бэкенд нужно обновить, для этого остановить бэкенд секунды на 2, после чего запустить. Всё продолжит работать, но запросы которые прилетели за эти 2 секунды nginx моментально отобьёт с кодом 502. Могу ли я его (nginx) как-то заставить ждать (например 30 секунд), прежде чем выдавать 502 ошибку? И только если в течение 30 секунуд бэкенд не проснулся и не ответил выдать 502.

Comment: В похожих вопросах на enSO пишут что нельзя

Comment: В жизни не поверю что те кому важны эти 2 секунды будут на SO вопросы задавать)

Comment: @InDevX ну раньше были не важны, теперь стали, но информацию о том как эти 2 секунды заставить сервис работать надо же где-то взять)

Comment: тут предлагают создать временного слушателя на другом порту/сокете, обновить приложение и вернуть слушателя обратно, интересно есть ли решения проще
https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-unit-updating-apps-with-100-percent-uptime/

Comment: Как заставить работать — просто запустить второй бэкенд

Comment: @Inventor это решается банально версионированием

Comment: @InDevX каким "версионированием"? Что вы под этим имеете ввиду?

Comment: @andreymal со вторым бэкендом засада. Иногда при обнове меняется структура базы данных. И если я её поменяю пока работает второй бэкенд, некоторые запросы во втором бэкенде могут сломаться, потому что он ожидает другой структуры, поднимать вторую базу, а потом непонятно как их синхронизировать, короче говоря не всегда это решение сработает

Comment: @Inventor поэтому крупные сервисы продумывают процесс изменения структуры БД так хитро, чтобы в переходный период с базой могли могли работать все версии бэкенда

Comment: @andreymal как же тогда сделать банальный rename колонки или таблицы? Если старая версия обращается к таблице с одним названием, а новая версия - с другим. Либо если в колонке меняется тип данных?

Comment: Мне кажется в таком случае проще найти способ придержать запрос на 1-2 секунды, чтобы за это время применились изменения к базе, перезапустился бэк

Comment: @Inventor как вариант — временно создать вторую колонку и временно записывать в обе колонки, потом отключить запись в старую колонку и ещё потом удалить её. И вот именно из за этого, что это слишком замороченно, лично я кладу болт на всю эту муть и тупо вырубаю бэк без оглядки на отваливающиеся запросы 

Comment: @Inventor если вы такое на проде вытворяете то вы явно что-то не так делаете... Надо архитектуру закладывать так, чтобы старый код не трогать, про версионирование гугл раскажет, там ничего особого нет

Comment: @InDevX не всегда хватает опыта или знаний заложить архитектуру правильно, и однажды приходит время, когда пора исправлять старые ошибки ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal с колонкой может быть ещё прокатит, но с таблицей всё сложнее, бэк вырубать не всегда есть возможность, например, если он должен получать какие-то вебхуки от сторонних сервисов. И не все эти сервисы дублируют эти вебхуки

Comment: @InDevX это в идеальном, несуществующем мире всё так сладко и гладко, в реальном приходит бизнес и говорит что вот в этой форме надо добавить новую колонку, а вот эту старую убрать. И как тут не трогать старый код? Заново переписывать сохранение этой формы в базу?)

Comment: @Inventor временно делать две таблицы? Для сравнения, когда ВКонтакте переезжал на новый бэкенд сообщений, старый и новый бэкенды продолжали сосуществовать несколько дней (не секунд)

Comment: @andreymal и всё-таки я склоняюсь к поиску решения придержать запрос на 1-2 секунды

Comment: Вообще, секунды — это довольно оптимистично, на крупных базах неосторожно сделанная миграция может растянуться на часы, а в особо запущенных случаях и на недели...

Comment: @andreymal конечно я это понимаю, в этом случае можно использовать 2 бэка. Я говорю о случаях когда сделать обратную совместимость невозможно или сложно (по типу создания доп таблиц и колонок). Rename всегда будет происходить за доли секунды. И естественно все эти миграции будут тестироваться на дебаге прежде чем идти в прод

Comment: @Inventor Зачем что-то переписывать если нужно изначально сделать так, чтобы добавить можно было что-то? Это не в идеальном мире, это просто продуманная архитектура и её отсутствие.

Comment: @InDevX какой у вас опыт работы? Неужели у вас всегда и везде получалось продумать, а что в будущем придёт бизнесу в голову?

Comment: @andreymal отмазки) обычно не исправляют старые ошибки а топчятся по старым

Comment: @Inventor никогда о бизнесе не думал) Думал только как абстрактно всё описать так, чтобы не было проблемой добавить что угодно новое. Были только проблемы с легаси, не всегда это гладко интегрировать получалось

Comment: @InDevX и что никогда не приходилось делать rename table или rename column?

Comment: @Inventor ну уж переименованием точно никогда не занимался

Comment: @InDevX рефакторингом и оптимизацией кода я так понимаю тоже? Даже самые крупные компании типа гугла занимаются этим, неужели у вас получилось изначально распланировать всё так, что рефакторинг не нужен? Даже гугл не смог...

Comment: @Inventor рефакторинг кода это вообще постоянно (не буквально), всегда думаешь как сделать что-то лучше.. Но это не изменение структуры, сущностей и т.п. Оптимизацией практически не занимаюсь, это редко бывает, если только алгоритм улучшить будет идея или что новое надумаю применить

Comment: @InDevX это изменение структуры тоже, иногда оказывается, что если данные хранить в немного другом формате, то скорость выполнения запроса возрастает в несколько раз.  Как быть в этом случае? Оставлять как есть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144417/discussion-between-indevx-and-inventor).

Comment: Можно написать имитацию на lua, но вообще надо либо забить на 2 секунды либо делать нормальные миграции

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос про беспрерывный деплой решается множеством разных способов. Но не совсем так.В вашем случае, как мне кажется, нужно попробовать proxy_send_timeout - задает таймаут при передаче запроса проксируемому серверу, т.е. время на передачу запроса, если за это время проксируемый сервер не примет новых данных - соединение закрывается. Но по умолчанию это время - 60 секунд. Т.е. если бэкенд моргнет на 2 секунды, это не должно влиять, а нужно дождаться ответа.  proxy_read_timeout - опять же время на чтение ответа от проксируемого сервера. Но тоже по умолчанию 60 секунд.

Comment: @Дмитрий proxy_send/read_timeout работают только когда уже установлено соединение с бэкендом, но в случае автора никакого соединения не будет, потому что бэкенд выключен